# What is the difference between $P(A \Delta B \Delta C)$ and $P(A \cup B \cup C)$?

Tags: probability

When $A,B,C$ are NOT Disjoint Events? 
I know that:
$$P(A  \Delta B  \Delta C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)−2P(A \cap B)−2P(A \cap C)−2P(B \cap C)+3P(A \cap B \cap C)$$
and $$P(A \cup B \cup C) =P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A \cap B)-P(B \cap C)-P(A \cap C)+P(A \cap B \cap C)$$
but I can't understand what is the difference between them and when I can use each one.

Comment: "When $A,B,C$ are (d)isjoint (e)vents" in the sense that $$A\cap B=B\cap C=C\cap A=\varnothing$$ then $$A\Delta B\Delta C=A\cup B\cup C$$ hence $$P(A\Delta B\Delta C)=P(A\cup B\cup C)$$ Is this your question?

Comment: my mistake i me when A,B,C are not Disjoint Events..

Comment: Then drawing a single Venn diagram should solve completely your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symmetric difference of the three events is the set of outcomes that belong to *exactly one* from the three events.   The union of the three events is the set of outcomes that belong to *at least* one from the three events.   The difference being the outcomes that belong to *two or three* from the three events.

Expressing the compound events as unions of disjoint intersections:

$\begin{align}A\Delta B\Delta C &=  (A\cap B^\complement \cap C^\complement)\cup (A^\complement\cap B \cap C^\complement)\cup(A^\complement\cap B^\complement \cap C)
\\[2ex]
A\cup B\cup C &={  {(A\cap B^\complement \cap C^\complement)}\cup {(A^\complement\cap B \cap C^\complement)} \cup {(A^\complement\cap B^\complement \cap C)} \\\cup {(A^\complement\cap B \cap C)}\cup {(A\cap B^\complement \cap C)}\cup{(A\cap B \cap C^\complement)}\\\cup{(A\cap B \cap C)}}\\[1ex]\text{so...}\qquad\\[1ex]\mathsf P(A\cup B\cup C)-\mathsf P(A\Delta B\Delta C)&={ {\mathsf P(A^\complement\cap B \cap C)} + {\mathsf P(A\cap B^\complement \cap C)} + {\mathsf P(A\cap B \cap C^\complement)} \\+ {\mathsf P(A\cap B \cap C)}} \\[1ex] &={{\mathsf P(A\cap B)}+{\mathsf P(A\cap C)}+{\mathsf P(B\cap C)}{-2\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C)}}\end{align}$

When $A,B,C$ are mutually disjoint, then the intersections in the last line are empty and thus the difference is a zero probability.

When $A,B,C$ are not so, then the difference is otherwise.

Comment: my mistake i me when A,B,C are not Disjoint Events..

Comment: Indeed they may not be, however, $(A\cap B^\complement\cap C^\complement)$ and $(A^\complement\cap B\cap C^\complement)$, et cetera, *are* pairwise disjoint.

Comment: So $A \triangle B \triangle C$ is not the same as $(A \triangle B) \triangle C$ despite $\triangle$ being an associative operation? That would be the first time I encounter that. Note that $x \in (A \triangle B) \triangle C$ iff $x$ is in an *odd* number of $A$,$B$ and $C$. That is, either in exactly one *or in all three* of them.